# Python how to remove unwanted commas in a dataframe containing lists as element

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe consisting list as a element which I got from the field measurements. I am processing each list for some operation. Surprisingly some random lists have additional comma at the end and this stops the whole process.

```
df = 
index      data
0          [1.002,1.001,1,1.005,1.001,1.001,1]
1          [2.002,2.001,2,2.005,2.001,2.001,2,,]
2          [4.002,3.001,2,1.005,2.001,6.001,5]
3          [1.002,1.001,1,1.005,1.001,1.001,9,,]
4          [8.002,1.001,7,1.005,9.001,8.001,12]
```

My dataframe has 90000 rows. An example row which gives error is given in index 1 and 3. These two lists have additional commas at the end. I want to eliminate those additional commas from the list. How to do it?

My present code:

```
 for index, row in iv_df.iterrows():
       row['data'] = np.setdiff1d(row['data'],[,])
```

Present output:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Expected output:

```
df = 
index      data
0          [1.002,1.001,1,1.005,1.001,1.001,1]
1          [2.002,2.001,2,2.005,2.001,2.001,2]
2          [4.002,3.001,2,1.005,2.001,6.001,5]
3          [1.002,1.001,1,1.005,1.001,1.001,9]
4          [8.002,1.001,7,1.005,9.001,8.001,12]
```

Any idea on how to achieve it?

Comment: what is the `dtype` of the `data` column ?

Comment: @Datanovice it is object type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['data'] = df.data.replace(to_replace=r',,', value='', regex=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: works for me, what if there is a single comma at the end ?

Comment: Then it would be `df['data'] = df.data.replace(to_replace=r',,|,', value='', regex=True)`

Comment: awesome solution, @Mainland this is the correct + better answer mate.

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon You are just great. Really great. Thanks a ton. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For a more elegant solution, try using `str.strip`:

```
df['Data']= df['Data'].str.rstrip(',')
```